# How to import an excel file with h2o

Tags: r, h2o

I am trying to import an excel file with h2o, but apparently it only works with .csv files, there is some other function besides this for .xls files. Is it possible to load files with this format ?.

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(x = iris, file = "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/iris.xls", row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(x = iris, file = "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/iris.csv", row.names = FALSE)

library(h2o)
h2o.init()

h2o.iris <- h2o.importFile(path = "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/iris.xls")
#h2o.iris <- h2o.importFile(path = "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/iris.csv")
```

Comment: read  as a normal csv or using `readxl` package and convert to a `h2o` object with `as.h2o`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
mydata<-readxl::read_excel("nelg.xlsx")
require(h2o)
h2o.init()          
as.h2o(mydata)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can read the excel file using normal **read.xlsx** and later convert it to h2o data frame using 
`train_h2o <- as.h2o(df)` # Creating h2o dataframe

Answer (score 0):

An additional option is rio:
`

```
library(rio)

data<-rio::import("C:/Users/USER/Desktop/iris.csv")
h2o.init()
h2o_data<-as.h2o(data)
```

`